# Deploy react bundle on jboss eap 7.3?

Tags: reactjs, jboss, web-deployment

I have a react project and I have created bundle using npm run build.
And in package.json I have also defined the homepage attribute.

So when I try to deploy this bundle file folder on tomcat, the tomcat serves the static react content.

But JBOSS gives 404 error, that I am not able to understand why?

So if it will not work, then how to deploy react project on jboss server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a location on where you want your bundle to 'live' and a handler to serve its content.
With the jboss cli you need to execute the following commands :

```
/subsystem=undertow/configuration=handler/file=react_handler:add(path="my_bundle_path")
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/location=\/my_react_app:add(handler="react_handler")
```

The first comment create an undertow handler to access the filesystem:
https://docs.wildfly.org/24/wildscribe/subsystem/undertow/configuration/handler/file/index.html

The 2nd command links this path to a resource location:
https://docs.wildfly.org/24/wildscribe/subsystem/undertow/server/host/location/index.html

Comment: Here, my_bundle_path will be the path of react bundle project inside jboss deployment folder

Comment: It is an absolute path but you can use ${jboss.home.dir} like the welcome-content or others properperties.

Comment: This worked, But PLEASE can you explain what these two lines of configuration are doing. And where these configs are stored on jboss server

Comment: And can I do this in production environment ?

Comment: Adding links to the Undertow configuration model. And I don't think those commands put your server in reload-required so you should be able to apply them on prod server.

Comment: it was working fine up until now, suddenly its giving this error, please help

{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0175: Resource [
    (\"subsystem\" => \"undertow\"),
    (\"server\" => \"default-server\"),
    (\"host\" => \"defaulthost\")
] does not exist; a resource at address [
    (\"subsystem\" => \"undertow\"),
    (\"server\" => \"default-server\"),
    (\"host\" => \"defaulthost\"),
    (\"location\" => \"/nucleus\")
] cannot be created until all ancestor resources have been added",
    "rolled-back" => true
}

Comment: "defaulthost" looks wrong to me as it should be default-host